# Replace each occurrence of string in a file dynamically

Tags: powershell

I have some text file which has some occurrences of the string "bad" in it. I want to replace each occurrence of "bad" with `good1`, `good2`, `good3`, ,, good100 and so on.

I am trying this but it is replacing all occurrences with the last number, good100

```
$raw = $(gc raw.txt)

for($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i++)
{
    $raw | %{$_ -replace "bad", "good$($i)" } > output.txt
}
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i = 1
$raw = $(gc raw.txt)
$new = $raw.split(" ") | % { $_ -replace "bad" , "good($i)" ; if ($_ -eq "bad" ) {$i++} }
$new -join " " | out-file output.txt
```

This  is good if the raw.txt is single line and contains the word "bad" always separed by one space " " like this: alfa bad beta bad gamma bad (and so on...)

Edit after comment:

for multiline txt:

```
$i = 1
$new = @()
$raw = $(gc raw.txt)
for( $c = 0 ; $c -lt $raw.length ; $c++ )
{
 $l =   $raw[$c].split(" ") | % { $_ -replace "bad" , "good($i)" ; if ($_ -eq "bad" ) {$i++} }
 $l = $l -join " " 
 $new += $l
 }

 $new | out-file output.txt
```

Comment: I think there is no split method, since its throwing an error that such method doesn't exist.

Comment: Shouldn't be `split()` better?

Comment: Can you try this: $raw.gettype() and tell me if return [string]? String type have split() method!

Comment: There's no split method for the object array returned from `Get-Content`. You'll need to use foreach.

Comment: You can just cast it to a string and then use split `[string] (gc raw.txt)`.

Comment: Not sure what text file you're dealing with but it returns `System.Object[]` from a typical multi line text file.

Comment: Even after casting to string, this did not work for me. The `bad` strings remained as-is.

Comment: @Christian: There are plenty of carriage returns. Can I remove the `$raw.split(" ")` altogether?

Comment: :(  Didn;t work again. Can you check with this snippet and see? http://pastebin.com/AvDVV80u

Comment: @KishorNanda : I  tryed using the content and saved as raw.txt, changed "txtb" with "txtc(counter)". and it works.

Comment: @Christian: It works! Thank you so much. Earlier I did not do it properly; my bad.

Answer (score 2):

For such things, I generally use Regex::Replace overload that takes a Matchevaluator:

```
$evaluator ={
$count++
"good$count"
}

gc raw.txt | %{ [Regex]::Replace($_,"bad",$evaluator) }
```

The evaluator also gets the matched groups as argument, so you can do some advanced replaces with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, replacing just one match at a time:

```
$raw = gc raw.txt | out-string
$occurrences=[regex]::matches($raw,'bad')
$regex = [regex]'bad'

for($i=0; $i -le $occurrences.count; $i++)
{
    $raw = $regex.replace($raw,{"good$i"},1)
}

$raw
```